# How to close dateInput in Shiny when user selects date?

Tags: r, date, shiny

I am using a dateInput object in my Shiny app. I want to close this once the user selects the date. Could you please advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: To be clear, I want to close the dateInput window, not disable it.

Comment: you want to close the dropdown menu?

Comment: maybe the `shinyjs` package can help you with that.